# Dynamically Load content and Navbar items are not working properly on ScrollSpy

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, scrollspy

I have requirements where few Data Content and their corresponding buttons are dynamically adding to NavBar. When content dynamically adding then after that ScrollSpy is not working properly and behaving very wearied.

Scrolling on content, no proper button is getting active.

I know it has something with Dynamic adding but don't know how to resolve it.

Jsfiddle:
In below JSFiddle, if you click on Welcome then two new content Div and tabs getting added and after that when you start scrolling, functionality are not working properly.

[http://jsfiddle.net/26e8nduc/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/26e8nduc/1/)

```
$('.navbar li a').click(function (event) {

var scrollPos = $('body > .container').find($(this).attr('href')).offset().top - offsetHeight;
$('body,html').animate({
    scrollTop: scrollPos
}, 500, function () {
    $(".btn-navbar").click();
});
return false;
```

});

Thanks for your response

Rushi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding elements dynamically, you will need to refresh scrollspy after the elements have been added.

From the latest bootstrap documentation http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#scrollspy

> **Methods**
>
> `.scrollspy('refresh')`
>
> When using scrollspy in conjunction with adding or removing of
>   elements from the DOM, you'll need to call the refresh method like so:
>
> ```
> $('[data-spy="scroll"]').each(function () {
>     var $spy = $(this).scrollspy('refresh')
> })
> ```